# Trying to `forge init` in Foundry but getting below error. Also tried to `git commit -a` but then also its not solving the problem

Tags: solidity, ether, testing, foundry, repositories

`$ forge init`
Error:
The target directory is a part of or on its own an already initialized git repository,
and it requires clean working and staging areas, including no untracked files.

Check the current git repository's status with `git status`.
Then, you can track files with `git add ...` and then commit them with `git commit`,
ignore them in the `.gitignore` file, or run this command again with the `--no-commit` flag.

If none of the previous steps worked, please open an issue at:
https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

Try running `forge init --no-git`. Worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try running `forge init --force .`

Answer (score 0):

Direct Answer:

```
forge install --no-git
```

Context:

Referring to [foundry docs](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-init), it mentioned:

```
By default, forge init will also initialize a new git repository, install some submodules and create an initial commit message. 
If you do not want this behavior, pass --no-git.
```

Just pass in `--no-git`.

So your command becomes `forge install --no-git`